# How to pop (read&remove) a line of a file?

Tags: text-processing, sed

I am trying to get the last line of a file and then delete it:

Read the line:

```
sed -n '$p' file
# or
tail -n 1 file
```

Remove the line:

```
sed -i '$d' file
```

This works, but is there a way to do this with just **a single command** ?

Comment: I'm not focused on `sed`. Any default tool will be fine.

Comment: In what way does `sed` not satisfy your requirements? To be able to suggest another way of doing it, we would need to know in what particular way `sed` is not good enough.  Or, do you want to perform _both_ operations in one command?

Comment: `sed` is fine, but I'd like to open the file just once. If there is no way to do this, I'll be fine.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Whatever the prevailing wisdom is, having to read a whole file each time in order to cut off its last line is **dumb**, no matter if it's done in a single process/command or two or three.

Unlike `sed -i`, `tail` is smart enough not to read a file from the beginning in order to determine what its last line is; also, linux has a `truncate(1)` utility, which combined with `tail` allows you to "pop" the last line(s) of a huge file in O(1) time:

```
# usage popline file [line_count, 1 by default]
popline()(LC_CTYPE=C; l=`tail -n "${2:-1}" "$1"; echo t`; l=${l%t}; truncate -s "-${#l}" "$1"; printf %s "$l")

$ wc -l /tmp/foo
3579500 /tmp/foo
$ cp /tmp/foo /tmp/foo1 && time sed -i '$d' /tmp/foo1

real    0m1.077s
user    0m0.457s
sys     0m0.156s
$ cp /tmp/foo /tmp/foo1 && time popline /tmp/foo1
 */

real    0m0.052s
user    0m0.002s
sys     0m0.003s
```

Comment: +1 very cool. `time popline file` -> `0m0.008s`  <----->  `time sed -i -e '${w /dev/stdout' -e 'd;}' file` --> `0m0.160s`

Comment: Nice clean command! What's the reason for the "t" marker character? Just to add one byte for the newline on the previous line?

Comment: @MikeHill  command substitutions like `\`...\`` in shell always strip the trailing newline, that's trick to preserve it without adding a newline if there isn't one already there. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15184414/10306503) for a nice complete explanation.

Comment: I wouldn't say `tail` finds the last line in O(1) time, but for the vast majority of files, the last line is not going to be a large fraction of the total contents of the file. Even `tail` still has to scan backwards from the end of the file to ensure that it finds the *last* newline character. (`tail` can't actually read backwards, but I assume it does something like read X bytes, and if there is no newline to mark the end of the next-to-last line, read the last 2X bytes, etc, until it finally finds the full last line.)

Comment: @chepner if the line length is a factor than it's O(l) vs. O(l * n), because even if you start from the beginning, you'll have to accumulate each line in a buffer the same way tail is doing with the last, because you have no way of knowing that the current line isn't the last.

Comment: Files are collections of bytes, not lines; it's really O(n) in the worst case because the last line might be the entire file, and you would have to read *all* the bytes to determine that. In *practice*, you only need to read a small fraction of those bytes,  so it "feels" like O(1). (Also, you don't necessarily have to buffer more than X bytes; once you find the last newline in a particular block, you can simply re-read every byte after that and write them directly to standard out.)

Comment: (For that matter, `sed` could analyze a simple script like the one Kusalananada shows and see that it, too, could find the last line the same way `tail` does. I assume that such optimizations aren't done because `sed` rarely gets such limited scripts.)

Answer (score 7):

The goal is to have a single command that outputs the last line of a file, and at the same time deletes that line from the original file.

```sh
sed -i -e '${w /dev/stdout' -e 'd;}' file
```

This would run the following `sed` script:

```
${
    w /dev/stdout
    d
}
```

This writes the last line to `/dev/stdout` and then deletes it.  All other lines are written back into original file through the `-i` option.

The script on the command line has to be split in two as there is no way to otherwise delimit the output filename of the `w` command (other than inserting a literal newline).

With `ed`:

```
ed -s file <<END_ED
p
d
w
END_ED
```

`ed` opens the file `file` and places the cursor on the last line of the file.  The first command prints that line to standard output, the second deletes it, and the last command writes the buffer back to the file. Using `ed` in this way may not be advisable on huge files.